# добавление своих классов в фабрику колбеков

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хочу добавить в поля фабрики свои классы. Вот код:

```
class MyCallbackFactory(CallbackData, prefix='any'):
    user: Player
    target: Player
    action: str
```

Сам класс:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
        self.is_alive = True
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.full_name} role:"
```